# BlueNRG Bluetooth: read central device name

Tags: c, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluenrg

I'm using the STM BlueNRG-MS chip on my peripheral device and after connection I'd like to read the name of the connected central device (android phone).

I thought I can do this directly in my `user_notify` routine which is registered as hci callback

```
  /* Initialize the Host-Controller Interface */
  hci_init(user_notify, NULL);
```

So on the `EVT_LE_CONN_COMPLETE` event, I take the provided handle for the central device and I use `aci_gatt_read_using_charac_uuid()` to read what I thought is the characteristic with the device name (uuid 0x2a00).

```
case EVT_LE_META_EVENT:
    {
      evt_le_meta_event *evt = (void *)event_pckt->data;
      switch(evt->subevent){
      case EVT_LE_CONN_COMPLETE:
        {
          evt_le_connection_complete *cc = (void *)evt->data;
                    GAP_ConnectionComplete_CB(cc->peer_bdaddr, cc->handle);
                    uint16_t uuid = 0x2a00;
                    resp = aci_gatt_read_using_charac_uuid(cc->handle, 0, 1, UUID_TYPE_16, (uint8_t*)&uuid);
                    LOG("GATT read status: %d", resp);

          enqueEvent(EVENT_BLE_CONNECTED);
        }
        break;
      }
    }
```

Long story short, it doesn't work. First thing I'm not sure about is, what is the `start_handle` and `end_handle` parameter of `aci_gatt_read_using_charac_uuid()`, it returns `ERR_INVALID_HCI_CMD_PARAMS`.

Can someone shed some light here?

**update**
What also puzzles me is that the function `aci_gatt_read_using_charac_uuid()` is nowehere referenced in the [BlueNRG-MS Programming Guidelines](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwimj778_-HxAhVawAIHHQ8wB3cQFnoECBQQAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.st.com%2Fresource%2Fen%2Fprogramming_manual%2Fdm00141271-bluenrg-bluenrgms-stacks-programming-guidelines-stmicroelectronics.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2UoG_VO9Td1BP2mHSmSmYM).

**update2**
I changed the function call to `aci_gatt_read_using_charac_uuid(cc->handle, 0x0001, 0xffff, UUID_TYPE_16, (uint8_t*)&uuid);` but I still get the `ERR_INVALID_HCI_CMD_PARAMS`. What which paramter could even be invalid? The uuid exists, I can read the device name if I use the BlueNRG GUI with a bluetooth dongle.

**update3**
Has anyone ever used this function or somehow managed to read a characteristic from a central device? I'd highly appreciate any help or hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out there are two bugs in the BlueNRG API.

In `bluenrg_aci_const.h` file the OCF code `OCF_GATT_READ_USING_CHARAC_UUID` shall be `0x119` instead of `0x109`.
And in the implementation of the aci_gatt_read_using_charac_uuid() function, there is a missing setting on event:

```
rq.event = EVT_CMD_STATUS;
```

Patching them fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, [The BlueNRG-MS Bluetooth® LE stack application command interface (ACI) - User manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00162667-the-bluenrgms-bluetooth-le-stack-application-command-interface-aci-stmicroelectronics.pdf)

page **75** - 4.6.25 `Aci_Gatt_Read_Charac_Using_UUID()`
and make sure you have called `Aci_Gatt_Init()`

The user manual is last revised July 2019, the document you link to is from 2018, don't know if this is why ?

The `start_handle` and `end_handle` is the range of handles in your service as pictured here -

[image]

Here is a [discussion](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X00009XkfLM/bluenrg-notification) to the closest thing I could find to match your question.

Comment: Thanks... I understand that I have handles for my local services and characteristics, that works like a charm, but what are the handles for a remote characteristic?

Comment: I know you can switch mode from peripheral to central and vice versa, that way you request the 0x180A, (Device Information Service) from the android phone.

Comment: So I first have to request the service before I can access one of its characteristics?

Comment: Officially yes, you have to discover the services first, then choose switch characteristic you want to access, now you can "avoid" this by being bonded to the device which will make service discovery time "zero" on subsequent connections, as the first discovery is cached, I know phones do this, but I don't know how to do it ;)

Comment: Still couldn't get it to work, I used `0x0001` as `start_handle` and `0xffff` as `end_handle`, but I still get the response `ERR_INVALID_HCI_CMD_PARAMS`. The same approach seems to work when I do it from the BlueNRG GUI

Comment: According to the description of `Aci_Gatt_Read_Charac_Using_UUID()` the return value `18` for `ERR_INVALID_HCI_CMD_PARAMS` shouldn't even be possible...